# Copy item from one three-dimension observablearray to another

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have some problems with relations in knockout.
In my project I copy item from constructionTypes to currentWindow.constructionParametres and then change through

```
this.currentWindow().constructionParametres().items()[0].currentStep(2)
```

But it changes in constructionTypes  too. I tried slice(), but gave no success.
What should I do?
Thanks.

```
function ReservationsViewModel() {

    this.constructionTypes = ko.observableArray([
        { id: 1, items: ko.observableArray([
            { type: 1, currentStep: ko.observable(1), steps: []},
            { type: 0, currentStep: ko.observable(1), steps: []},
            { type: 0, currentStep: ko.observable(1), steps: []},
            { type: 0, currentStep: ko.observable(1), steps: []}
        ])
        },
        { id: 2, items: ko.observableArray([
            { type: 1, currentStep: ko.observable(1), steps: []},
            { type: 2, currentStep: ko.observable(1), steps: []},
            { type: 0, currentStep: ko.observable(1), steps: []},
            { type: 0, currentStep: ko.observable(1), steps: []}
        ])
        }
    ]);     

    this.currentWindow = ko.observable({
        id: ko.observable(0),
        name: ko.observable('Need 1'),
        constructionParametres: ko.observable( this.constructionTypes().slice()[0] )
    });

    this.currentWindow().constructionParametres().items()[0].currentStep(2);
    this.currentWindow().constructionParametres().items()[0].currentStep(3);


}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xveEP/72/

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. What is the *expected* output, and why? Can you show the various solutions you've tried and why/how they didn't work? Are you perhaps just looking for some way to deep copy items (e.g. like [this](http://api.jquery.com/clone/))?

Comment: Not a solution, but you should probably create different ViewModels that have kind of relationships - it will be at least more readable and maintainable, even if it doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.slice` in your case creates a copy of array, but array items are *references* to objects. So copying part of array is not a solution since items in original and copied arrays will reference to the same objects.

You may consider to use built-in `ko.toJS` function that creates *plain* copy of your object (*plain* means that all observables will become non-observable). Maybe this approach is not what you are expecting but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/ostgals/xveEP/73/